# Const variable still being reassigned in chess challenge

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a challenge on code wars and I can't seem to figure out why const variable is being changed. I thought this was the place to use a constant like this. I just want to reset the piece location to what it was when checkDiagonal() is called but it always stays to what it was after the first while loop finishes.

function checkDiagonal(piece){

```
const store = piece;
var current = piece;

// northwest
while(current[0] && current[1] > 0){
  current[0] -= 1;
  current[1] -= 1;
  if(spaceCheck(current)){
    return true;
  }
  if(spaceCheck(current) == "break"){
    break;
  }
}

current = store;
console.log("piece1: " + piece + " current :" + current + "store: " + store);

//northeast
while(current[0] > 0 && current[1] < 7){
  current[0] -= 1;
  current[1] += 1;
  if(spaceCheck(current)){
    return true;
  }
  if(spaceCheck(current) == "break"){
    break;
  }
}

current = store;
console.log("piece2: " + piece + " current :" + current + "store: " + store);


//southwest
while(current[0] < 7 && current[1] > 0){
  current[0] += 1;
  current[1] -= 1;
  if(spaceCheck(current)){
    return true;
  }
  if(spaceCheck(current) == "break"){
    break;
  }
}

current = store;
console.log("piece3: " + piece + " current :" + current + "store: " + store);


//southeast
while(current[0] && current[1] < 7){
  current[0] += 1;
  current[1] += 1;
  if(spaceCheck(current)){
    return true;
  }
  if(spaceCheck(current) == "break"){

    break;
  }
}

return false;
```

};

function spaceCheck(location){

```
  if(chessboard[location[0]][location[1]] == '♔'){
    console.log("Check detected " + location); 
    return true;      
  }
  if(chessboard[location[0]][location[1]] != ' '){
    console.log("Piece blocking check" + location);
    return "break";      
  }
  else{
    console.log("False" + location);
    return false;
  }
```

};

/// Bolded the part thats getting me, how can I just "reset the piece" back to what it was at the function call?

**piece1: 3,0 current :3,0store: 3,0**

False 2,1

False 2,1

False 1,2

False 1,2

False 0,3

False 0,3

**piece2: 0,3 current :0,3store: 0,3**

False 1,2

False 1,2

False 2,1

False 2,1

Piece blocking check3,0

Check by Queen(Diag)

False 2,0

False 2,0

False 1,0

False 1,0

False 0,0

False 0,0

False 1,0

False 1,0

False 2,0

False 2,0

Piece blocking check3,0

Check by Queen(Linear)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is scope. Basically you are declaring the const inside a function so the const only lives for the duration of that specific function call and once the call is done the variable will be destroyed (which is why you would also be unable to access it outside the function).

So when you call your checkDiagonal function the second time the const is being re-declared from scratch.

There is an explanation of this here: https://wsvincent.com/javascript-scope-closures/

Hope this makes sense.

Edit:
After some digging it turns out the problem seems to be that piece is an object and is therefore being passed by reference rather than by value. This means that when current was updated it kinda updated all three (technically all three are the same object in memory)

There is a good article on these two here: https://hackernoon.com/grasp-by-value-and-by-reference-in-javascript-7ed75efa1293

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! I'm still a bit confused though. I'm only calling the function once. The function contains 4 while loops for the different directions. I'm just wanting to reset the piece location (In this case, its 3,0) at the start of every while loop, but it retains the coordinate from the end of the last while loop.

Comment: Hi Dillon, My apologies i think i have misread your code being put in is the piece variable you are passing in an object not an integer in which case it would pass by reference not by value. Can you try rather than const store = piece;
var current = piece; using const store = {...piece}; var current = {...piece}

Comment: Ah thank you! I believe "pass by reference" is what was tripping me up. I'll look into that more.

Comment: Your more than welcome ill update my answer just incase anyone else has the same issue.